# VBA XML how can I get the Parent attribute from a child node?

Tags: xml, vba, nodes

I have a search screen where you can select different options (items that are child nodes). After hitting search I would like togo through a XML document and retrieve the parent node attribute. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<brands>
  <BrandA Name="A Brand">
     <Color>Black</Color>
     <Thickness>1"</Thickness>
     <Texture>Smooth</Texture>
  </BrandA>
  <BrandB Name="B Brand">
     <Color>Red</Color>
     <Thickness>2"</Thickness>
     <Texture>Smooth</Texture>
  </BrandB>
  <BrandC Name="C Brand">
     <Color>Green</Color>
     <Thickness>3"</Thickness>
     <Texture>Rough</Texture>
  </BrandC>
</brands>
```

If someone is searching from a "Rough" texture how could I get the parent node of BrandC Name?

VBA CODE:

```
For Each T In objDom.getElementsByTagName("Texture") 

    MsgBox T.Text 'For testing to see what it returns (all 3 textures).

If ComboBox3.Value = T.Text Then
    'For testing: This returns all matching textures that was selected.
    MsgBox T.ParentNode.Text 
End If
```

So this returns everything Brand name, color, thickness, texture. I just need the Brand Name IE "C Brand".

Comment: It would help to show your "search" code.  `parentNode` is likely what you want though - then `getAttribute()`

Comment: @Tim Williams I tried parentNode but that returns everything under that node. IE brand name, color, thickness, and texture.

Comment: What Tim was trying to say: Show your VBA code. It doesn't matter what you say you've tried until you show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `T.ParentNode.Text` I believe you will want `T.ParentNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text`

Comment: It worked. Now what if I have another parentnode over that one. How do I get the second level parentnode?

Comment: I figured it out, for every level I have to add an extra ParentNode so would be ParenNode.ParentNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("AnotherName").Text

Comment: Moving through the XML DOM (and also an HTML DOM with the HTML library) is actually a lot of fun. You can move through it with Node.Parent.Parent.NextSibling.Child.Child.text, for instance, which would kick you up to the node's grandparent, over to it's sibling (the node's great aunt/uncle) and then to their grand child and pull their text. The trick is to use the `.getElementsByTagName` or other Element search functions to get as close as possible, then use the relationships to narrow in one what you want.